# Unions of two Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let X be topological space (X doesn't have to be Hausdorff), A and B are the subspace of X (with relative topology). I know if A and B are both Hausdorff and A and B are disjoint, then the disjoint union of A and B is still Hausdorff. What about the situation if the intersection of A and B are not empty? Is there any simple counterexample? thanks!

Comment: X is Hausdorff?

Answer (score 3):

The so-called "line with two origins" is a counterexample.

See https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/the-line-with-two-origins/

Comment: How do you realize this as an intersection of subsets in a Hausdorff space?

Comment: Question doesn’t assume X is Hausdorff, so this should be a counter example

Comment: I think OP is asking "if $A$ and $B$ are Hausdorff subspaces and are not disjoint, must their union be Hausdorff?".

Comment: @MPW The OP is asking both about union and intersection if I am not mistaken.

Comment: X doesn't have to be Hausdorff, A and B are just two Hausdorff subspace of X with the relative topology of X

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the topology you are using on $A\cup B$. The natural one is the subspace topology, and in this case, as a subspace of a Hausdorff space $X$, it is also Hausdorff.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. I believe OP is asking the following:  If $A$ and $B$ are Hausdorff subspaces of $X$, must $X$ necessarily be Hausdorff? You do not know beforehand whether or not $X$ is Hausdorff, just that the two subspaces $A$ and $B$ are Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, X doesn't have to be Hausdorff

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal counterexample. Let $X$ be $\{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology, let $A = \{0\}$ and $B = \{1\}$. The subspaces $A$ and $B$ are trivially Hausdorff, but the subspace $A \cup B$ is already $X$, which is not Hausdorff.

Comment: This is a trivial counterexample for sure, I considered about this, but I hesitated about whether one point set is Hausdorff. I wonder is there any non-trivial example?

Comment: @QIRUNCONG Sure. Just use the same idea and built something more complicated. But this counterexample is the core reason why the answer is negative.